# How can I fill a table view based on some calculous, resorting to django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, windows

So I'm starting a django web application and I'm new using django... So please be patient with me.
So, in my project I have two views:
1- a user profile;
2- a sort of a calculator, that can give several results at the same time according to the user input

So, to start, here is my model.py:

```
class Calanalisis(models.Model):
    sequence = models.CharField(max_length=120000)
    gc_content = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=1000)


    def gc_content_cal(self):
        if self.sequence == True:
           gc_content= round((self.sequence.count('C') + 
           self.sequence.count('G'))/len(self.sequence) * 100,1)
           return gc_content
```

forms.py:

```
class AddSequenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Calanalisis
        fields = ('sequence',)
```

views.py:

```
def calc_sequence(request):

    sequence_items=Calanalisis.objects.filter(person_of=request.user)
    form=AddSequenceForm(request.POST)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=AddSequenceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile=form.save(commit=False)
            profile.person_of = request.user
            profile.save()
            return redirect('calc_sequence')
    else:
        form=AddSequenceForm()

    myFilter=SequenceFilter(request.GET,queryset=sequence_items)
    sequence_items=myFilter.qs
    context = {'form':form,'sequence_items':sequence_items,'myFilter':myFilter}
    return render(request, 'Add_Calc.html', context)
```

And now I want to introduce gc_content_cal to be calculated in the table. When I introduce the sequence, the sequence appears in the table, however the gc_content_cal continues to be 0, like the image shows.

[image]

Can someone help me please?

This is my template: base.html

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="login">
        <div class="login-screen">
            <form method="POST" action="" class="login-form form-inline">
              {% csrf_token %}
              
                {% for field in form %}
                <h5 class="form-labels">
                {{ field.label }}
                </h5>
                {{ field }}
                 
                {% endfor %}
           
                <input class="btn mt-2" type="submit" value="select">

            </form>
           
        </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered text-center mt-3">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Sequence</th>
                    <th scope="col">GC</th>
      
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for oligoseq in sequence_items %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ oligoseq.sequence }}</td>
                <td>{{ oligoseq.gc_content }}</td>

            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>  
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Can you also post your template as well?

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe just added my template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, the problem. I created a function that saved the objects of the class. Like this:

```
class Calanalisis(models.Model):
    sequence = models.TextField()
    gc_content = models.FloatField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    person_of = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):# new
        if self.sequence != None:
            self.gc_content = gc_content(self.sequence) #round((self.sequence.count('C') + self.sequence.count('G'))/len(self.sequence) * 100,1) if self.sequence else 0
            

        super(Calanalisis,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put what you want to show on template in render function.

Comment: I already have the sequencing appearing, but how can I call de function to calculate the GC value and put it on the table?

Comment: Can you add some examples of code the OP should use in order to achieve this? As it is this answer is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `gc_content_cal` model method in your template like so.

```
<tbody>
{% for oligoseq in sequence_items %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ oligoseq.sequence }}</td>
    <td>{{ oligoseq.gc_content_cal }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

As you have it the template just accesses the `gc_content` attribute of your model which is set to the value 0 judging by your output. The `gc_content_cal` doesn't store a value in your `gc_content` attribute, it just returns a value based on what's in the `sequence` attribute.